# ExtJs 4 Reload Application

Tags: extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

In my application all component's titles/texts are localized based on store loaded before Application launch. In application i have button that changes store url and reloads the store to switch language.  The problem is that all the classess are already loaded so components are rendered with previous locale. Here is the code of the button:

```
tbar: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    id: 'btn-test',
    text: 'xxx',
    handler: function() {
        lang = 'en';        
        i18n.getBundlestore().load({url:'/GSIP/resources/gsip/i18n/bundle-' + lang + '.properties'});

        //bun = Ext.create('I18N.ResourceBundle'); 

        Ext.getCmp('mainview').destroy();

        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            id: 'mainview',
            layout: 'border',
            items: [
                {
                 xtype: 'gsip_mainpanel',
                 region: 'center',
                 items: [{
                     xtype: 'gsip_categoriestabpanel'
                 }]

                }
            ]
```

The exact same viewport creation is in my Application.js. lang and i18n are global variables. Old viewport is destroyed and new is created but how to force to reload classess. I dont want to use window.location.

Code updated:

```
handler: function() {

        lang = 'en';        

        Ext.getCmp('mainview').destroy();

        i18n.getBundlestore().load({url:'/GSIP/resources/gsip/i18n/bundle-' + lang + '.properties',
            callback: function() {
                Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                    id: 'mainview',
                    layout: 'border',
                    items: [
                        {
                         xtype: 'gsip_mainpanel',
                         region: 'center',
                         items: [{
                             xtype: 'gsip_categoriestabpanel'
                         }]

                        }
                    ]            
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

CategoriesTabPanel:

```
Ext.define('GSIP.view.CategoriesTabPanel' ,{
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
alias : 'widget.gsip_categoriestabpanel',   
layout: 'fit',
items: [{
    xtype: 'gsip_planytabpanel',
    title: i18n.getMsg('key-1')
},{
    xtype: 'gsip_adresytabpanel',
    title: i18n.getMsg('key-2')
}],
initComponent: function() {

    this.callParent(arguments);

}
```

});

and ResourceBundle (i18n variable is an instance of this class):

```
Ext.define('I18N.ResourceModel',{

        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['key', 'value']
    });

    Ext.define('I18N.ResourceStore',{
        extend: 'GSIP.core.RegisteredStore',
        model: 'I18N.ResourceModel',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/GSIP/resources/gsip/i18n/bundle-' + lang + '.properties',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'pl',
                successProperty: 'success'
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.define('I18N.ResourceBundle' ,{

        config: {
            bundlestore: Ext.create('I18N.ResourceStore'),
        },
        constructor: function(config) {
            this.initConfig(config);

            return this;
        },
        getMsg: function(key) {

            return this.bundlestore.getAt(this.bundlestore.findExact('key', key)).get('value');

        }
        },function(){
            //callback function, called before store load :(
        }
    );
```

Comment: Although possibly not solving your problem, there's an issue with your code: The store load is asynchronies, so there's a good chance the new viewport will be created before the store is loaded. You should really destroy the old view and create the new one within a callback passed to the load method.

Comment: You are right the viewport should be recreated in callback function. I updated code. It still doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: Could you please provide the code for 'gsip_categoriestabpanel'? I suspect you either define configs there with reference to objects.

Comment: Code updated. Thank you for your time. Tha lang variable is created at beginning of my Application.js (var lang = 'pl').

Comment: Within the definition of `widget.gsip_categoriestabpanel` you set `items` as a config. This means it will always reference the same object (and not the updated one). As first step, you should move the `items` definition to `initComponent`, there you can also `console.log(i18n)` to see it's the right one.

Comment: Izhaki you are great! Indeed that was the problem. Now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the definition of widget.gsip_categoriestabpanel you set items as a config. This means it will always reference the same object (and not the updated one). As first step, you should move the items definition to initComponent, there you can also console.log(i18n) to see it's the right one.